# Can't parse certain information applying conditional statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to parse the emails of some companies out of a webpage. The problem is that the emails are either within `span[data-mail]` or `span[data-mail-e-contact-mail]`. If I try the two conditions seperately, I can get all the emails. However, when I try to wrap them within `try:except:else` block, they no longer work. Where am I going wrong?

[website link](https://www.krak.dk/byggefirmaer/s%C3%B8g.cs?consumer=suggest)

This is the script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "replace with the link above"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
for links in soup.select("article.vcard"):
    try: #the following works when tried individually
        email = links.select_one(".hit-footer-wrapper span[data-mail]").get("data-mail")
    except: #the following works as well when tried individually
        email = links.select_one(".hit-footer-wrapper span[data-mail-e-contact-mail]").get("data-mail-e-contact-mail")
    else:
        email = ""
    print(email)
driver.quit()
```

When I execute the above script, It prints nothing. They both work, if printed individually, though.

Comment: You can try to use single CSS selector for both cases: `select_one('.hit-footer-wrapper span[data-mail], .hit-footer-wrapper span[data-mail-e-contact-mail]')`

Comment: Thanks sir for the information. I though that as well but the problem is: how can i print them using it's attribute because they are different `.get("data-mail")` or `.get("data-mail-e-contact-mail")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that exception will not be raised with your code as both `get("data-mail")` and `get("data-mail-e-contact-mail")` will return value (empty or not), but not exception

Try below code to get required output:

```
for links in soup.select("article.vcard"):
    email = links.select_one(".hit-footer-wrapper span[data-mail]").get("data-mail") or links.select_one(".hit-footer-wrapper span[data-mail-e-contact-mail]").get("data-mail-e-contact-mail")
    print(email)
```

Comment: Omg, it is possible to go like this as well!! Get back to you sir.